# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - How to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I am having some issues.

I'm using "express": "^4.17.1" and  Node.js v14.4.0. and FIREBASE

I have this ERROR: "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"
How can I solve the problem?

my backend code:

```
app.post("/business/:businessID/Party/:partyID/editParty", function(req, res) {

  let businessID = req.params.businessID;
  let partyID = req.params.partyID;
  let ref = database.ref('parties/' + partyID);

  ref.update({
    name: req.body.name,
    date: {
      day: req.body.date,
      openHour: req.body.openingHour,
      closeHour: req.body.closingHour
    },
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error! can't update party");
      console.log(error);
      return res.redirect("/business/" + businessID + "/Party/" + partyID + "/editParty");
    } else {
      console.log("party updated!");
      return res.redirect("/business/" + businessID + "/Party/" + partyID);
    }
  });
});
```

my frontend code:

```
<form action="/business/<%=party.businessID%>/Party/<%=party.id%>/editParty" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Party!</button>
</form>
```

The error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:533:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at done (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:10)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:260:5)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\amzal\Desktop\Mingle\Mingle Website For Businesses\Mingle Website App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
```

Comment: You are trying to return from an asynchronous call.

Comment: So how the code should look like?